# How to find the most frequent value in a select statement as a subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssms

I am trying to get the most frequent Zip_Code for the Location ID from table B. Table A(transaction) has one A.zip_code per Transaction but table B(Location) has multiple Zip_code for one area or City. I am trying to get the most frequent B.Zip_Code for the Account using Location_D that is present in both table.I have simplified my code and changed the names of the columns for easy understanding but this is the logic for my query I have so far.Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
Select
           A.Account_Number,
           A.Utility_Type,
           A.Sum(usage),
           A.Sum(Cost),
           A.Zip_Code,
           ( select B.zip_Code from B where A.Location_ID= B.Location_ID  having count(*)= max(count(B.Zip_Code)) as Location_Zip_Code,
            A.Transaction_Date


From 
            Transaction_Table as A Left Join
            Location Table as B  On A.Location_ID= B.Location_ID


Group By   
              A.Account_Number,
              A.Utility_Type,
              A.Zip_Code,
              A.Transaction_Date
```

Comment: What's wrong with the results of your current query?   What result are you getting, and what are you trying to get instead?

Comment: that the only message im getting with my query "Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 35
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I come up with:

```
Select tt.Account_Number, tt.Utility_Type, Sum(tt.usage), Sum(tt.Cost),
       tt.Zip_Code,
       (select TOP 1 l.zip_Code
        Location_Table l
        where tt.Location_ID = l.Location_ID 
        group by l.zip_code
        order by count(*) desc
       ) as Location_Zip_Code,
       tt.Transaction_Date
From Transaction_Table tt 
Group By tt.Account_Number, tt.Utility_Type, tt.Zip_Code, tt.Transaction_Date;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases are a good thing.  However, they should be abbreviations for the tables referenced, rather than arbitrary letters.
- The table alias qualifies the column name, not the function.  Hence `sum(tt.usage)` rather than `tt.sum(usage)`.
- There is no need for a join in the outer query.  You are doing all the work in the subquery.
- An `order by` with `top` seems the way to go to get the most common zip code (which, incidentally, is called the mode in statistics).

Comment: Thank you , It helped me ! and about the aliases :| since I was changing the column names and adding aliases to simplify it, just didn't notice I was not following the correct way. But thanks for the tips! :)